# ASP.NET Core: How does one find out which nuget package a given function is in

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

There are a lot of questions on here with the form "A does not contain a definition for B" related to ASP.NET Core. The answers are always that you need the right Nuget package installed, and the right using statement to match. The using statements are not usually a problem to figure out at least in Visual Studio where it automatically suggests them, but knowing which Nuget packages to install seems to be a matter of trial and error as far as I can see.

Is there a documentation site, or some other straightforward method for finding out what package is needed for a given function? The source is available but I was unable to find any systematic organisation of packages there. There probably is a system but I can't find it.

For examples see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IApplicationBuilder+does+not+contain+a+definition+for

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, Intellisense in Visual Studio is smart enough to suggest nuget packages:

[image: Intellisense suggesting a package based on type name]

As you can see, there may be more than one match, so you still need to do the research which is the right one for you.

This only works for some nuget packages, not all (I think it's working for the most popular). In the remaining cases, it's usually sufficient to put the type name into a search engine to find a match for the full type name, which usually leads to the assembly / nuget package. There is no one single resource, as there is no one single repository for packages (nuget is only the most common, but then again, there are company private feeds etc.)